# Plot error bar in matplotlib on both axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I want to plot 2D data points with errors on each axis in python. I have used `errorbar` from matplotlib:

```
x=[393.995,394.87,422.965,423.84,437.49,438.360,466.965,467.84]
y=[1.2625,0.7575,1.2625,0.7575,1.2625,1.7675,2.2725,2.7775]
errors=[0.486731,0.00955756,0.111786,0.412761,0.240057,0.228817,0.222496  ,0.24288]
errorbar(x, y, xerr=errors, yerr=errors, ecolor='k', fmt='o', capthick=2)
```

But it shows only errors on y-axis. I have no idea why.

**The plot:**

[image: The plot]

Comment: Please add sample data. The values for `x`, `y` and `errors`. Post only a small sample of a few points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is the relative value of the errors and the `x` data. You are simply not able to see the bars. To understand the issue look at the following two examples:

Invert the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
x=[393.995,394.87,422.965,423.84,437.49,438.360,466.965,467.84]
y=[1.2625,0.7575,1.2625,0.7575,1.2625,1.7675,2.2725,2.7775]
errors=[0.486731,0.00955756,0.111786,0.412761,0.240057,0.228817,0.222496  ,0.24288]
errorbar(y, x, xerr=errors, yerr=errors, ecolor='k', fmt='o', capthick=2) #invert x and y
```

[image]

Reduce the value of your `x`.

```
x=[3.93995,3.9487,4.22965,4.2384,4.3749,4.38360,4.66965,4.6784] #x=x/100
y=[1.2625,0.7575,1.2625,0.7575,1.2625,1.7675,2.2725,2.7775]
errors=[0.486731,0.00955756,0.111786,0.412761,0.240057,0.228817,0.222496  ,0.24288]
plt.errorbar(x,y, xerr=errors, yerr=errors, ecolor='k', fmt='o', capthick=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very, that explains why